# Python - passing class instantiation to a function

Tags: python-3.x

I need to pass the class instantiation to a function.
This is what i wrote so far:

```
def func(dog):
    print(dog.get_name)

def main():
    new_dog = dog(name, age, weight)
    func(new_dog)
```

but when i try to execute it i get the following error message:

```
<bound method animal.get_name of <classes.dog object at 0x7f9611002b70>
```

Basically i have a class file with the following classes:

- animal - Mother class(it include the name getter)
- dog - Child class of animal
- cat - Child class of animal

What i'm doing wrong?

--EDIT--
Structure of the classes:

```
class animal:
    # public vars
    name = ""
    age = 0
    weight = 0.00
    animal_type = ""

    # public constructor
    def __chars(self):
        print("His name is: " + self.name)
        print("He is: " + str(self.age) + " y.o.")
        print("His weight: " + str(self.weight) + " Kg")
    def __init__(self, name, age, weight, animal_type):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.weight = weight
        self.animal_type = animal_type
        print("A new animal has been created!")
        self.__chars()
    # public methods
    def eat(self):
        print("The animal eat!")
    def drink(self):
        print("The animal drink!")
    def play(self):
        print("The animal plays!")
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    # public destructor
    def __del__(self):
        print('\n' + self.name + "has died :(")

# Child classes
class dog(animal):
    __dlevel = None # dangerous level, it can be 0, 1 or more, it's private

    # private methods
    def set_dlevel(self, dlevel):
        self.__dlevel = dlevel
        print("Dangerous level set!")

    def get_dlevel(self):
        # CHeck if the level is define
        if not self.__dlevel:
            print("Dog dangerous level not found")
            sys.exit(1)
        # if is equal or more than 1 is dangerous
        if int(self.__dlevel) >= 1:
            print("The dog is dangerous, be careful while playing with him!")
        # otherwise it's a quiet dog
        elif int(self.__dlevel) <= 0:
            print("The dog isn't dangerous")
```

Comment: We would need to see the classes you defined, but what has most likely happened is that `dog.name` is a function, which is why, instead of printing the name of the dog, it prints the function details.

Comment: @Jono2906 i've added the classes code

Comment: You have nothing in that code that sets the name.

Comment: I ran the code you provided, and it seemed to work -- I saw nothing about `<bound method>` in the output.

Comment: Yes, in the constructor: `self.name = name`

Comment: What Jono said. `print(dog.get_name())` is what you need to do. Note the '()' after 'get_name', you need this to actually call your method. The output you got is **not** an error message, it is the standard string representation of a method. That is what happens when you call print on the method itself because you forgot to call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the real problem: i was printing the function, not calling it.
So instead i've used

```
def func(animal):
    print(animal.get_name())

def main():
    new_dog = dog("max", 14, 11, "dog")
    func(new_dog)
```